# Why is there a difference b/w window.clearTimeout and clearTimeout on IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, overriding

I am trying to override **clearTimeout** function which works perfectly fine in all browsers except IE(tested in IE8)

```
clearTimeout = function(){};
```

IE8 gives the following error:

```
Object doesn't support this action
```

But when I do,

```
window.clearTimeout = function(){};
```

It works perfectly fine overriding clearTimeout. Why is this behaviour?

Also, everywhere in my code I am calling **clearTimeout** directly and not as **window.clearTimeout**. So even if I override clearTimeout(by the second way), the native clearTimeout is called and not the overridden clearTimeout. What can be a workaround for this?

Comment: why are you overriding default behavior?

Comment: I am writing QUnit testcases in which I am trying to track whether clearTimeout was called or not with a specific argument.

Comment: The window object is a host object, clearTimeout is a host method. They do not have to comply with ECMA-262 and can do what they like (almost).

Comment: couldn't you wrap `(set/clear)(interval/Timeout)` in your own functions?

Comment: @DanielA.White Is that questions for me? Cause I think this is what I am trying to do(if I am not wrong) or is there any other way to wrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In IE, initially, the property setTimeout exists on the prototype of
>   window, not on window itself. So, when you ask for window.setTimeout,
>   it actually traverses one step on the prototype chain to resolve the
>   reference. Similarly, when you ask for setTimeout, it traverses down
>   the scope chain, then to window, then down the prototype chain to
>   resolve the reference.
>
> I suspect that IE has a built-in optimization where it automatically
>   caches the resolution of implied globals that are discovered all the
>   way down on the prototype of the global object. It would have good
>   reason to do so, as these are commonly requested references, and
>   traversing that chain is costly. However, it must be setting this
>   reference as read-only, since it's just a caching optimization. This
>   has the unfortunate side-effect of causing an exception to be thrown
>   when attempting to assign to the reference by using it as an lvalue.

Source: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2011/4/Replacing-setTimeout-Globally

Comment: I had a quick try setting window.constructor.prototype.setTimeout in IE8 but that didn't seem to do anything - probably because window is a native object of type DispHTMLWindow2.